# Get filenames from find command

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a find command in the form:

```
find ${SRC} -type f -level 0 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

This is in a ksh script, where `${SRC}` is the directory I am searching in.

My question is, what's the best way to get a list of the files that `-exec` operated on?

*EDIT* Specifically, I am looking to get the file names into a string variable.

Comment: Why not find ${SRC} -type f -level 0 -print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can extend exec to multiple commands with sh:

```
file_list=$( find ${SRC} -type f -level 0 -exec sh -c 'echo {} ; rm -f {}' \; )
```

but in this case you can just do:

```
file_list=$( find ${SRC} -type f -level 0 -print -exec rm -f {} \; )
```

Comment: can be just a `... -print -exec ...`